# C# Basic parameter passing

Tags: c#, parameters, get, set

I am new to C# I am trying to pass a value to a method but receiving 0.Creating an instance to the main method of calc and calling the calc methods in main.

```
public void test()
{
var calc = new Calc();
calc.Add(1);
var actual = calc.Value;
}

public class Calc
{
        public int Value{
            get; set;
        }

        public void Add(int value)
        {
            int result = value + value;

        }
```

I am trying to set the current value, how could I do that?

Comment: Your `Add` method does not change the value of the `Value` property of your class instance. It only returns the added value.

Comment: You never set `Value` and you never assign the result from `calc.Add(1)`. What did you expect it to do?

Comment: How can I set Add value to set?

Comment: I would recommend a tutorial or a good book. Stackoverflow is not a substitute for a proper learning medium. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Joroen thank you I will read this. the Get/set is the problem I think.

Comment: in `Add`, you will need to change the value Property directly, i.e. `Value += value`. You should also consider changing the `Value` property to a `private set`, if the only way for external code to change the value is via methods like `Add`

Comment: You are lacking basic programming knowledge (or at least object oriented knowledge) I suggest you find a general tutorial/book to read or youtube has plenty of C# tutorials if you don't like reading like me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest refactoring it a bit so the variable names are more clear. Your initial problem is that you weren't doing anything with the result, when really you wanted to set it to your property.

```
public class Calc
{
    public int CurrentValue { get; set; }

    public void Add(int number)
    {
        this.CurrentValue = this.CurrentValue + number;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of your `Add` method is not stored anywhere, i.e. the after the method is complete all the memory allocated while it was executed, is released. If you wish to save the result of your method you should either return it (which will require changing your method's prototype) or save it in a member of you class and access it with an appropriate property or getter-method.

Your class should be something like this:

```
public class Calc
{
        private int result;
        public int Value
        {
                get { return result; } 
                set { result = value; }
        }

        public void Add(int value)
        {
            result = value + value;

        }
}
```

Please note that currently the `Add` methods just saves the result of two times of the value of the sent parameter `value` into the class member `result`

Comment: I am trying to add it to my a variable result and trying to pass it to my get/set. As result is declared above int Value

Comment: Thanks I had that all this time but think I have kind of got it.

Comment: @StevenJones, Good to hear, best of luck with `C#`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something more like this:

```
public class Calc
{
        public int Value{
            get; private set;
        }

        public void Add(int value)
        {
            this.Value += value;
        }
}
```

Note I changed your `Value` to have a private setter, so that only the `Calc` class has access to change its value, whereas other objects are still able to retrieve its value.

Notice the change in the `Add` function, we're adding the `value` passed into the function onto your `Value` property.  In your case you were just creating a new variable `result` in each call of the `Add` method, and then doing nothing with it.

You can see it in action [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RXgB6C)